# django: exclude models from migrations

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

In my django application (django 1.8) I'm using two databases, one '`default`' which is MySQL, and another one which is a schemaless, read-only database.
I've two models which are accessing this database, and I'd like to exclude these two models permanently from data and schema migrations:

- `makemigrations` should never detect any changes, and create migrations for them
- `migrate` should never complain about missing migrations for that app

So far, I've tried different things, all without any success:

- used the `managed=False` Meta option on both Models
- added a `allow_migrate` method to my router which returns `False` for both models

Does anyone have an example of how this scenario can be achieved?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Usually `managed=False` is the way. What's the problem with it?

Comment: include the code part you done also because as @Ivan suggests it is the way

Comment: I believe that this post answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33820715/how-to-disable-migration-from-one-model-of-an-app-in-django

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26789687/3042057

Answer (score 2):

> So far, I've tried different things, all without any success:
>
> - used the managed=False Meta option on both Models

That option (the `managed = False` attribute on the model's meta options) seems to meet the requirements.

If not, you'll need to expand the question to say exactly what is special about your model that `managed = False` doesn't do the job.

Answer (score 2):

I thought, I have a problem with makemigrations. It pretends to make migration on `managed = False` model, but no SQL code generated for this model

Here is my example, model `Smdocumets` unmanaged, and no SQL code was generated.

> python manage.py makemigrations

```
Migrations for 'monitor':
  monitor\migrations\0005_auto_20171102_1125.py
    - Create model Smdocuments
    - Add field sid to db
    - Alter field name on db
```

> python manage.py sqlmigrate monitor 0005

```
BEGIN;
--
-- Create model Smdocuments
--
--
-- Add field sid to db
--
ALTER TABLE "monitor_db" RENAME TO "monitor_db__old"; 
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You have the correct solution:

> used the managed=False Meta option on both Models

It may appear that it is not working but it is likely that you are incorrectly preempting the final result when you see `- Create model xxx` for models with `managed = False` when running `makemigrations`.
How have you been checking/confirming that migrations are being made?

`makemigrations` will still print to terminal `- Create model xxx` and create code in the migration file but those migrations will not actually result in any SQL code or appear in `Running migrations:` when you run `migrate`.