# how to disable migration from one model of an app in django

Tags: django-models

I have an application which is using 2 database, 1 is default another is custom. So 2 of my model are using default database, else are using custom database. i do not want to migrate custom database model while running 'make migrations' command. please help it out.

Comment: What the goal of that?

Answer (score 32):

You can selectively disable migration for one or more Django-Models by setting `managed = False` in Django [Model Meta options](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#managed).

```
from django.db import models
class LegacyModel(models.Model):
   class Meta:
       managed = False
```

Comment: But `python3 manage.py makemigrations` still creates a migration for them.

Answer (score 19):

It's worth mentioning that although the `managed` flag is set to `False` a migration for the model will still be created but no sql creation script. 
The sql of a migration ca be check using `manage.py sqlmigrate appname migration`

Answer (score 4):

> Options.managed Defaults to True, meaning Django will create the
>   appropriate database tables in migrate or as part of migrations and
>   remove them as part of a flush management command. That is, Django
>   manages the database tables’ lifecycles.
>
> If False, no database table creation or deletion operations will be
>   performed for this model. This is useful if the model represents an
>   existing table or a database view that has been created by some other
>   means. This is the only difference when managed=False. All other
>   aspects of model handling are exactly the same as normal.
>   [From the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/options/#managed)

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
   class Meta:
       managed = False
```

Answer (score 0):

How it worked for me:

1. Set: `managed = False`
2. `python manage.py makemigrations`
3. `python manage.py migrate`
   (he writes the creation of tables in the migration file, we ignore it).
4. Set: `managed = True` (repeat step 2 and 3)
5. Done (now when adding a new column, the table will not be created in migrations)

Ps. (This worked when the tables were not in relations, when there was a relation between the tables, it took one more time to do manipulations with managed = True/False)